# iOS compass roll over calculation

Tags: ios

I have what I thought was a simple problem.  I have my subject wearing the iphone on their chest. They need to walk a few feet then turn 180 degrees, I’m using the mag compass heading, but when the compass “rolls over”  i.e goes from 359 to 1 or from 1 to 359 it gets confused. I’ve tried putting switches and stuff (see code below) but it still doesn’t work.  I’m sure others have confronted this before. Any ideas, tricks, techniques?
Thanks.

```
 // Turn completion logic here
 if (self.firstTimeInTurnCheckingOne) {
      self.firstTimeInTurnCheckingOne = FALSE;
      self.startingCompass = newHeading.magneticHeading;
      self.lastCompass = newHeading.magneticHeading;
      self.currentCompass = newHeading.magneticHeading;
      NSLog(@"First time in: %f", self.startingCompass);
 }

 NSLog(@"Before roll check - start: %f Last: %f current: %f", self.startingCompass, self.lastCompass, self.currentCompass);

 // check to see if compass rolled over
 if (!self.compassRolled) {
      if ((fabs (self.lastCompass - self.currentCompass) > 340)) {
      NSLog(@"@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@it rolled %f  %f", self.lastCompass, self.currentCompass);
      self.compassRolled = TRUE;
      if (self.currentCompass > self.lastCompass) {
           self.currentCompass = self.currentCompass - 360;
           self.startingCompass = self.startingCompass - 360;
           self.rolledDown = TRUE;
           NSLog(@"Rolled Down");
      } else {
           self.currentCompass = self.currentCompass + 360;
           self.startingCompass = self.startingCompass + 360;
           self.rolledUp = TRUE;
           NSLog(@"Rolled Up");
           }
      }
 }

 self.lastCompass = self.currentCompass;
 NSLog(@"After roll check - start: %f Last: %f current: %f", self.startingCompass, self.lastCompass, self.currentCompass);
 NSLog(@"Difference: %f", fabs(self.startingCompass - self.currentCompass));


 if (!self.turnOneComplete) {

      if ((fabs (self.startingCompass - self.currentCompass)) > 120) {
           NSLog(@"Turn Calc: %f", (fabs (self.startingCompass - self.currentCompass)));
           NSLog(@"Turn One Complete");
           self.turnOneLabel.hidden = NO;
           self.turnOneComplete = TRUE;
           self.compassRolled = FALSE;

           self.startingCompass = newHeading.magneticHeading;
           self.lastCompass = self.startingCompass;
           self.currentCompass = self.startingCompass;
           NSLog(@"Turn One complete setup: %f", self.startingCompass);

      } else {
          // do something here
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set aside 180º for a moment and imagine a more general requirement: you must write code that returns the number of degrees that a user has turned, and the answer must be correct for any number of degrees.

It's clear that your current approach is not workable, because if a user turns 720º, the result would probably be 0º. The implementation misses a bunch of information by only storing the initial (`startingCompass`) and final (`currentCompass`) states, so there's no way to account for rolling over.

What you should do is define an accumulator variable that is incremented or decremented continuously as the user's heading changes. Start a timer with sufficiently high frequency, and on each timer tick compute the heading difference between now and the previous tick. Then add that value to the accumulator.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I'm still stuck on what to do when the compass rolls over.I understand you suggestion, but the sticking point is the rollover - so when the compass goes from 359 to 1, I want to increment the accumulator variable by two.

Comment: Why would it roll from 359 to 1? Shouldn't it pass through 0? A clock doesn't jump from 11:59 to 12:01

Comment: Yes it does go to zero first. I was just using an example